# split zones on external monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, productivity

I've decided to add a second display to my computer. I can see the advantages, but I'll like to get more from this setup.

I'll like to have a different zone on the second monitor. For example, when I press the Win+Left key, the window is positioned to the left side of the screen on occupies 50% of the surface. I'll like to occupy 75% every time, permanent and automatically.

Do you know any free app which can split the display in a custom manner?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by virtual edges?

Comment: as in splitting into many monitors

Comment: Your question is much improved, however you're asking for an application to do this, which is off-topic. Instead, simply state what your goal is and ask how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right of the bat you can move apps between monitors, you only have to arrange them in "Display config".

There a bunch of software out there. But I can tell you that DisplayFusion is the thing for me. It has a bunch of characteristics, like monitor spliting and hot keys for things you would usually find in Linux, like resize to top half up or top half down(in Windows you can only do it left or right).

There is a free version, with 30 days trial full, and the paid version. It's pretty cheap for what you get IMHO. You can even buy it from steam when it goes for sale for like $10 dollars.